# Download a PDF report ShinyApp

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny

I'm trying to run  [this shiny app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html)
By copying to my computer like :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    title = 'Download a PDF report',
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        helpText(),
        selectInput('x', 'Build a regression model of mpg against:',
                    choices = names(mtcars)[-1]),
        radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                     inline = TRUE),
        downloadButton('downloadReport')
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput('regPlot')
      )
    )
  )
server <- function(input, output){
  regFormula <- reactive({
    as.formula(paste('mpg ~', input$x))
  })

  output$regPlot <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
    plot(regFormula(), data = mtcars, pch = 19)
  })

  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },

    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
      ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

But then when I press download I have the following error :

[image: Error]

I'm using a company computer which blocks some ports. Does this error has something to do with that ? Can somebody help please ?